# テスト環境のHTMLからルートパスで書かれた本番環境のリソースを参照したい

Tags: html, .htaccess

本番サイト（`https://www.mydomain.or.jp/`）のファイルをコピーし修正したものを、テストサイトで確認しています。

本番とテストは別のサーバーです。

ファイルのリンクはルートパスから書かれており、テストサイトでリンク切れとなってしまいます。

そこで以下のように`.htaccess`をつかってファイルパスを読み替えて参照するようにして、リンク切れを解消したいです。（リンクのコードを書き換えない方法としたい）

beforeはリンク切れが起こっているもので、afterのような絶対パスにリダイレクトさせたいということです。

この場合`.htaccess`の書き方、設置場所はどのようになりますか？

`/`から始まる全てのリンクを差し替えたいです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

**before**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/common/css/import.css" type="text/css">
```

**after**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.mydomain.or.jp/common/css/import.css" type="text/css">
```

次の記事にならって、下のように`.htaccess`を作成しましたがうまくいきません。
https://qiita.com/awesam86/items/de58cf6afc83b0d52890
どこが誤りでしょうか？

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.((gif|png|jpe?g|css|ico|js|svg))$ https://www.mydomain.or.jp/$1.$2
```

`mydir/index.html`で`index.html`がリンク切れを起こしている時、`.htaccess`を
`mydir`と同じ階層に格納。`mydir` 配下の同様のリンクを全て差し替えたい。

Comment: この場合は HTML のファイル指定を修正するのが取るべき対応じゃないかと思います。

Comment: 本番サイトのファイルをテストサイトで確認しており、リンク切れの箇所がたくさんある状況です。

Comment: 「ルートパス」での記述も許容されていること今を知りました。テストサイト側でWebサーバのドキュメントルートが適切に設定されているかも確認した方が良さそうです。

Comment: この RewriteRule だとループすると思います。
それとも、リダイレクト先 https://www.mydomain.or.jp/ は別サーバー(本番サーバー)なのですか？

Comment: @TaichiYanagiya はい、別サーバーになります。テストサーバーに置かれたファイルから、本番サーバーへリダイレクトしたいです。

Comment: それは大事な情報に見えるので質問の本文にも書いていただきたいです（私はその情報を見るまでこの質問が何を聞きたいものなのか分かっていませんでした）。他にも関係しそうな環境情報があれば随時載せていただけるとありがたいです。

Comment: @nekketsuuu ご不便おかけしてすみません。質問を少し修正しました。

Comment: ありがとうございます！　念の為確認なのですが、こちらテストサーバーにも本番サーバーと同じファイルを置くのは非現実的である、という条件下だという認識で良いでしょうか。テスト環境が本番環境に依存しているのがやや不自然に思えています。

Comment: @nekketsuuu おっしゃる通り、本番環境にファイルを上げられず、更新対象の2ファイルのhtmlだけをテスト環境にあげて確認したいという状況です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> mydir/index.htmlでindex.htmlがリンク切れを起こしている時、.htaccessを
>   mydirと同じ階層に格納。mydir 配下の同様のリンクを全て差し替えたい。

この場合、`.htaccess` を置くのはリダイレクトしたいリソースに対応するディレクトリです。例: `ドキュメントルート/common/.htaccess`
ブラウザは `mydir/index.html` を取得したあとに `mydir/` にはアクセスしません。

テスト環境であれば、`.htaccess` を使わずに `httpd.conf` に書いてしまってもいいかもしれません。

- そもそも mod_rewrite が使える環境かどうかも要確認です
- .htaccess が使える設定かどうかも要確認です
- 私だったら `index.html` に `<base href="http://www.mydomain.or.jp/">` を書くだけで済ませるかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます！<base href="http://www.mydomain.or.jp/"> でいけるかもです！ちょっとやってみます。

Comment: いけました！！ありがとうございます！！